# Spring integration poller thread exhusted

Tags: string, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using String Integration DSL mail to receives email from a POP3s mail server. After few hours I see the poller stops polling the mail server and do not process the email. I can login to mail server and see the emails are their in the mail server. Could you please review the below and let me know what incorrect here

```
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow emailFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(Mail.pop3InboundAdapter(config.getMailUri())
                .javaMailProperties(p -> 
    emailInflowConfiguration.javaMailProperties(p))
                .embeddedPartsAsBytes(true).maxFetchSize(1)

    .shouldDeleteMessages(true)
                .javaMailAuthenticator(config.mailAuthenticator()),
            e -> e.autoStartup(true)
                .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(5000,
                    1000)))
        .channel(MessageChannels.direct("pop3Channel"))
        .handle("pop3Handler", "handleMessage")
        .get();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to see thread dump to determine the waiting threads and where.

Usually thread pool is exhausted when there is a component waiting for reply but there is no one from downstream. Not likely it is with your code snippet. So, we definitely need more information. For example what does that  `pop3Handler` do?

Comment: Here is the thread dump https://www.dropbox.com/s/onj89bawv02exha/thread.dump?dl=0 , well the pop3Handler parser the receipt email and push further downstream. Anyway I have a _**catch (Throwable error) { Thread.interrupted();**_ in the handler